# Load page within javascript

Tags: javascript, load

Is there a method in javascript to load a page without actually show that page?

I want to load a php page which will handle the database insertion tasks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use AJAX to get/send data to the serverside?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you can use the `XMLHttpRequest` for this.

here is a example

```
function done() {
  console.log(this.responseText); // The response from the server
};

var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

XHR.onload = done; // Set the onload function
XHR.open("get", "something.php", true); // Type & File
XHR.send(); // Send the request
```

Here is some documentation on that [MDN XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)